# Pull to refresh sounds

Tags: ios, user-interface, audio, uirefreshcontrol

Where would I play sounds for both the 'slide' and 'pop'.

I understand the pop sound would be played when endRefreshing is called - But what type of Control Event on the UIRefreshControl would be appropriate for playing the Slide sound?

Answer (score 0):

#### Playing the Slide sound once the user kicks off a refresh

Depends on how you are starting the refresh control. If you start the refresh control in code, then do it right after you call `refreshControl.beginRefreshing()`. If you are using the `UITableViewController` version to get notified of it, then you are looking for the value changed event. Register for the start of the refresh with `refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "anAction", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)`. You can play the slide sound in the `anAction()` method, which you should define.

#### Playing the Slide sound once the user starts the pull down to refresh

Set yourself as the `UITableView`'s delegate, which also conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. You can implement `scrollViewWillBeginDragging()` and play the sound when the user drags down the table view.

Comment: The problem I'm having is the "ValueChanged" is only triggered when the pull to refresh is released - I need the slide sound to come before then